# Make svg rect clickable with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a fairly straight forward svg rectangle that I need to make clickable with jquery, but I can't get it to work.
I'm using Bootstrap, but don't think that has anything to do with it.

**SVG element**

```
<svg id="clickme" width="100%" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="40" fill="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="5"></rect>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em"> text </text>
</svg>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    console.log('NO 1');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported jquery lib? Works fine..

```js
 

$('#clickme').click(function(){
    console.log('NO 1');
});
```

```html
<style>
    #clickme{width:100px;}
    #clickme:hover{cursor:pointer;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <svg id="clickme" width="100%" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="40" fill="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="5"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em"> text </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I had imported it. 
I couldn't figure it out, so I deleted everything and started over and now it works. So there was something interfering.